# How CMake finds packages

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I have a CMake that adds OpenCV to a project.

I add OpenCV to my project using this code:

```
if (MSVC)
    file(TO_CMAKE_PATH $ENV{OPENCV_ROOT} OpenCV_DIR)
    IF(NOT OpenCV_DIR)
        MESSAGE( FATAL_ERROR "Please point the environment variable OpenCV_ROOT to the root directory of OpenCV installation. required openCv V 4.2.x as minimum")
    ENDIF()
    set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF)
    find_package(OpenCV 4.2.0 REQUIRED)
else (MSVC)
    set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS ON)
    find_package(OpenCV COMPONENTS core highgui imgproc imgcodecs videoio photo stitching flann ml features2d calib3d objdetect REQUIRED)
endif(MSVC)
```

If I don't define `OpenCV_root` environment variable, CMake can not find OpenCV. But if I define it, I am getting this warning:

```
CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:36 (find_package):
  Policy CMP0074 is not set: find_package uses <PackageName>_ROOT variables.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0074" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  Environment variable OpenCV_ROOT is set to:

    D:\local\opencv

  For compatibility, CMake is ignoring the variable.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
```

So how CMake can find OpenCV, if I did not define `openCV_root` environment variable?

The same question is also valid for other packages (such as boost, which I am getting the same warning), should we define an env variable or not?

If I don't define an env variable, how OpenCV would find the package?

Comment: Did you read the documentation for [`find_package()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#search-procedure)?

Comment: @squareskittles: The documentation notes, that `find_package` uses `<PackageName>_ROOT` variable for discover the package. The asker sets this variable exactly for this purpose ... and gets the [CMP0074](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/policy/CMP0074.html) warning which looks very confusing even for me. So the questions stated in the post are very reasonable.

Comment: @Tsyvarev You are correct. So does the question become "*why is CMP0074 not set?*". CMake should default to use the `NEW` behavior, correct?

Answer (score 2):

The CMP0074 policy's [description](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/policy/CMP0074.html) tells:

> In CMake 3.12 and above the `find_package(<PackageName>)` command now searches prefixes specified by the `<PackageName>_ROOT` CMake variable and the `<PackageName>_ROOT` environment variable... This policy provides compatibility with projects that have not been updated to avoid using `<PackageName>_ROOT` variables for other purposes.

That is, in your project you need **eliminate using** `OPENCV_ROOT` variable for purpose other than **directly** affecting on `find_package(OpenCV)` behavior.

In newer CMake this variable is used **automatically**:

```
# This sets CMP0074 to NEW.
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12) # Or bigger version
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF)
# If `OPENCV_ROOT` variable is set, it will be used in the next call without a warning.
find_package(OpenCV 4.2.0 REQUIRED)
```

If you want your project to have a hint about OpenCV installation for other purposes, use a variable with different name.

```
# We want to support old CMake versions too!
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11) # Or lower version

# Use `OPENCV_INSTALL_PREFIX` environment variable for set `OpenCV_DIR`, which helps CMake to find OpenCV.
# This setting works for both new and old CMake versions.
file(TO_CMAKE_PATH $ENV{OPENCV_INSTALL_PREFIX} OpenCV_DIR)
IF(NOT OpenCV_DIR)
    MESSAGE( FATAL_ERROR "Please point the environment variable OPENCV_INSTALL_PREFIX to the root directory of OpenCV installation. required openCv V 4.2.x as minimum")
ENDIF()
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF)
find_package(OpenCV 4.2.0 REQUIRED)
```

Alternatively, you may disable CMP0074 policy and use OPENCV_ROOT variable for your purposes. But this is **not recommended**:

```
# 'find_package' won't use `_ROOT` variable. This suppress the corresponding warning. 
cmake_policy(SET CMP0074 OLD)
file(TO_CMAKE_PATH $ENV{OPENCV_ROOT} OpenCV_DIR)
IF(NOT OpenCV_DIR)
    MESSAGE( FATAL_ERROR "Please point the environment variable OpenCV_ROOT to the root directory of OpenCV installation. required openCv V 4.2.x as minimum")
ENDIF()
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF)
find_package(OpenCV 4.2.0 REQUIRED)
```

Comment: does this mean that to find a package, we should define <packageName>_root? I remember that in the older version, we would have opencv_dir and for boost, i think it was boost_root.

Comment: Setting variable `<packageName>_ROOT` is not the only way to find a package. One could set, e.g., `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable. Setting `<packageName>_DIR` variable works too.

Comment: Notice: For method 2, if you already installed something globally in `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`, cmake will ignore the `<packageName>_DIR` variable you set, it's priority is not as same as `<PackageName>_ROOT`.